# Why Spring use ForkPoolJoin instead of ThreadPoolTaskExecutor with @Async?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor, forkjoinpool

For my studies, I'm working on a Spring Boot REST API. I'm supposed to reduce the execution time of the code when it received a request. So, I thought that make the code asynchronous would be a good idea. But, unfortunately, I face some problems with Spring for this, and despite the few hours of research online to find a solution, I didn't find anything. Let me explain :

To optimize my code, I decided to use `@Async` Spring Annotation. For this, I created an AsyncConfiguration class who looks like this :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration {

    @Bean(name = "asyncExecutor")
    public Executor asyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(50);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsynchThread-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
    
}
```

Usually, the `asyncExecutor()` method returns the `Executor` class or sub-class that must be used by Spring for async calls. In this case, it's a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. And the majority of my code is annotated with `@Async` to use my `asyncExecutor`, like this :

```
@Async("asyncExecutor")
    public CompletableFuture<User> calculateRewards(User user) {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            logger.info("Calculating Reward for user : " + user.getUserName());
            List<VisitedLocation> userLocations = user.getVisitedLocations();
            List<Attraction> attractions = gps.getAllAttraction();
        
            for(VisitedLocation visitedLocation : userLocations) {
                for(Attraction attraction : attractions) {
                    if(user.getUserRewards().stream().filter(r -> r.attraction.attractionName.equals(attraction.attractionName)).count() == 0) {
                        if(nearAttraction(visitedLocation, attraction)) {
                            user.addUserReward(new UserReward(visitedLocation, attraction, reward.getAttractionRewardPoints(attraction.attractionId, user.getUserId())));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return user;
        });
    }
```

But, here's the point : when I run the code, Spring DON'T use my `asyncExecutor()` bean. How do I know that ? First, when I call an annotated method, in the terminal, here's what I see :

```
2022-10-27 00:26:24.688  INFO 41436 --- [onPool-worker-4] c.T.T.service.TourGuideMainService       : Calculating Reward for user : internalUser919
```

The **"[onPool-worker-4]"** is the Thread name, or at least the end of the Thread name. But it's not supposed to be named like that. If you look at my `asyncExecutor()` method above, you can see that there is a `executor.setThreadNamePrefix("AsynchThread-");`. If the code was working as intended, the Thread should be called "AsynchThread-4", but It's not.

Secondly, I decided to run my code in Debug mode, and I went into the Debug menu of VS Code, and I dicovered two things :

1 - When I run my stress test who make 1000 calls of `calculateRewards()` simultaneously, there is only 11 Threads created. Considering the execution time of the `calculateRewards()` method AND the fact that the Executor have its `maxPoolSize` by default (i.e. `Integer.MAX_VALUE`), there should be more than 11 Threads ;

2 - The entire name of the Threads when they are created is **"[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-4]"** ;

It seems that Spring is using the `ForkJoinPool` class to create Threads, and it don't ever consider the configuration of my Executor. I have no idea of why it's doing that, I never used `ForkJoinPool` at all, and like I said, I didn't find anything when searching about that online.

So, why Spring is using `ForkJoinPool` instead of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` for async methods in my code ? And most important : how can I address that ?

(I hope that it's understandable...)

EDIT 1 : During some random testing, I found that, if Spring seems to use some `ForkJoinPool` Threads to execute my code, it create a "AsynchThread" anyway but don't use it. That's even more confusing... -_-"

Comment: the approach seems perfectly valid  - can you please see if the bean with the name ```asyncExecutor``` is created

Comment: Yes, I verified with Spring Actuator, and the `asyncExecutor` bean is actually created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you are using `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` to produce your `CompletableFuture`.

This method will fork off a task running in the ForkJoinPool.commonPool() and execute your Supplier in that task.

Since spring will supply the executor and run your entire method asynchronously, you shouldn't need to use the `supplyAsync` function with a lambda.  Instead your async method should look something like this (inside of your service):

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  
  ...

  @Async("asyncExecutor")
  public CompletableFuture<User> calculateRewards(User user) {
    logger.info("Calculating Reward for user : " + user.getUserName());
    List<VisitedLocation> userLocations = user.getVisitedLocations();
    List<Attraction> attractions = gps.getAllAttraction();

    for(VisitedLocation visitedLocation : userLocations) {
      for(Attraction attraction : attractions) {
        if(user.getUserRewards().stream().filter(r -> r.attraction.attractionName.equals(attraction.attractionName)).count() == 0) {
          if(nearAttraction(visitedLocation, attraction)) {
            user.addUserReward(new UserReward(visitedLocation, attraction, reward.getAttractionRewardPoints(attraction.attractionId, user.getUserId())));
          }
        }
      }
    }

    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(user);
  }

}
```

If you autowire your service into a `CommandLineRunner` that executes your method, you can use this runner to see that spring will handle executing your method asynchronously using the `Executor` you have defined in your configuration.

For example:

```
@Component
public class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

  private final MyService service;

  public Runner(MyService service) {
    this.service = service;
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<User> user1 = service.calculateRewards(new User("user1"));
    CompletableFuture<User> user2 = service.calculateRewards(new User("user2"));
    CompletableFuture<User> user3 = service.calculateRewards(new User("user3"));

    CompletableFuture.allOf(user1,user2,user3).join();
  }

}
```

Comment: Well, it's even worse nom.

With that solution, the ForkJoinPool class is not used either, so there is just NO async at all.

Comment: Then perhaps you are instantiating your service that has the `calculateRewards` method incorrectly?
If it is instantiated locally and called directly then the method will not run asynchronously.  It must be It must be created inside a `@Configuration` class or picked up by `@ComponentScan`.

The method will be run asynchronously using the configured `Executor` if your service is created in this manner.

Comment: Actually, my Service class is annotated with `@Service` and the main class of my code is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication`, which trigger component scanning. Given that the Service class is in a sub-folder of the folder where is the main class, the Service class is supposed to be picked up by `@SpringBootApplication`.

Comment: I added an example of how you can autowire your service into a runner.  If you do this, you will see that spring is using the configured executor under the hood to actually run your method asynchronously.